# Sorting a range, Excel says range is empty

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I try to sort a range (containing 3 columns) I want to sort the data on the second column and if there are two things the same in that column I want it to sort it via the first column.

The second and the first column are always filled in.

Here is the line I use, but I keep getting the error:

> Runtime error 1004: The sort reference is not valid, make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank

`Target.Sheets("SheetToSort").Range("A1:C" & m).Sort Key1:=Range("B1:B" & m), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("A1:A" & m), order2:=xlAscending`

Target is a defined workbook, the sheet exists, cells `"A1:C" & m` contain data only column C might have empty spaces but I don't sort anything on that column.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just make sure all your ranges refer to the same sheet, so amend it like this:

```
Target.Sheets("SheetToSort").Range("A1:C" & m).Sort _
Key1:=Target.Sheets("SheetToSort").Range("B1:B" & m), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Target.Sheets("SheetToSort").Range("A1:A" & m), Order2:=xlAscending
```

I know I've had issues before where this has happened because the `Range` object, when you don't specify the sheet, might be pointing to a different sheet than you think.

Comment: Therefore also read [VBA Best Practices: Never assume the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet).